# Angular : Update model from directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-digest

I have a fiddle up here: http://jsfiddle.net/KdkKE/44/

What I'd like to do create a 'toggle' component, basically a custom checkbox but with html that changes if it is true or false, which is bound to a boolean in a controller.

When the user clicks on the toggle the model is updated the directive's view changes. It's similar to the examples at the end of the directives doc http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive but the state would be bound so that it would be correct on startup.

```
var app = angular.module('App', []);

function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.init = function() {
        $scope.foo = true
    }
}

 app.directive('toggle', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            transclude: true,
            scope: {
                label: '@',
                ngModel: '='
            },
            template: 
                '<div style="cursor: hand; cursor: pointer">{{label}}: {{ngModel}}</div>',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
                element.bind('click', function() {
                    scope.ngModel = false;
                    attrs.$set('ngModel', false);
                    console.log('plz', attrs.ngModel);
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

-

```
<div ng-app="App">
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl" ng-init="init()">
        <p>Foo in Ctrl: {{foo}}</p>  
        <toggle label="Foo" ng-model="foo"></toggle>
    </div>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think you are just missing the use of [`$apply`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#$apply). See it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/4TnkE/

```js
element.bind('click', function() {
    scope.$apply(function() {
        scope.ngModel = !scope.ngModel;
    });
});
```

It can also be used like this to avoid nesting in another function:

```js
element.bind('click', function() {
    scope.ngModel = !scope.ngModel;
    scope.$apply();
});
```